# "...which I did.", "...but I'm not." - are they correct?

Tags: ellipsis, contractions, parallelism

I've been wondering, are structures like the ones mentioned in the title considered correct? Is it perfectly fine to use them, or do they sound overly colloquial? Let's focus on the three examples:

> a) "Wish me luck!" said Ana.
>
> "I do" was my only response.

I can't think of any other way I could have phrased it without sounding overly wordy.

> b) He told me I couldn't have predicted what the next card would be, but I truly did.

Again, this one sounds entirely idiomatical to my non-native ear.

> c) He told me to rethink my actions, which I did, and go to church, which I didn't.

But in this one, for whatever reason, the second part is where I start to have doubts. Is it only me, or is the contracted form more natural than its longer version?

Comment: They sound OK to me, if a bit slangy and informal.  The only one I might change is #2, to "He told me I couldn't have...but I truly **had**", because "I *had* predicted it."

Comment: Is "could" possible?

Comment: But then again, do you not think that, once we remove the nonrestrictive clauses, the sentence would sound peculiar with another "to"? "He told me to rethink my actions and to go to church"?

Comment: **truly** is regional in AmE.   Northerner: I'm really sorry.. Southerner: I'm truly sorry.  But there is also **really and truly**....

Answer (score 1):

Your two phrases are correct and often used

> He told be to buy the red car, **which I did**.
>   Mom wanted me to wash the dishes, **which I did**.
>
> She is hungry, **but I'm not**.
>   They are from America, **but I'm not**.

Comment: Okay, and what about the short questions and answers? Is it completely natural to respond with a simple "I do" in my a) example? If somebody said "We can't go there, you can't even drive a car!", would it be acceptable to respond with: "I can" rather than "yes, I can"? Or perhaps it'd sound better phrased like "well, I can" if I didn't want to stick to the second option?

Comment: And regarding the questions. Is it correct to say: "I'm not hungry. Are you?" or "I knew you'd fool me! Or did you?"

Comment: @Bebop Not really. I would expect you to respond with the performative "Good luck!"

Comment: For me :-), If one responds to "Wish me luck!" with "I do!", is sounds like they are holding something back, best is to use "Good luck!". If you say "we can't go there..." you are including yourself, "How will you get there, you can't even drive a car, but I can *(drive you)*." at which point they will ask you to drive them. Subtle point: "Well, I can" is good for "Who can drive us there?", and depending on intonation can be interpreted as "Well, I can, *(if you really want me to and are going to twist my arm and make my life miserable if I don't)*".

Comment: Also, since you already said "you **can't even** drive" (a put down), if you say "I can", "I do" without a "but" it will sound like you are gloating.

Comment: But is it even correct to give a natural sounding short answer in such a form, without a yes/no, preceding the other words? Does the answer to "Are you hungry?" that goes simply like: "I am" have some air of awkwardness to it? Perhaps I should stick to the "Yes, I am" or "Yes" option?

Comment: Again depends, a native would say: "Are you hungry?" -> "Yes I am!", "Who's hungry?" -> "I am!"

Comment: But at the same time a native would have no problem answering the question "Do you love me?" with "I do!", correct? If so, what makes it different from the question about hunger?

Comment: And what about the questions? Is the "I'm not hungry. Are you?" also considered weird and thus should be rephrased?